# GAN for specific face attribute modification

Tags: generative-adversarial-networks

A recent paper "MagGAN High Resolution Face Attribute Editing with Mask Guided GAN" published this month (October 2020) describe how an approach has been developed to deal with specific face attribute editing.

The thing is that in this paper and related work (StarGAN, CycleGAN, AttGAN, STGAN ...) seems to tackle the process of adding / editing a face attribute (e.g. adding a hat or mustache...), but not really modifying the face attribute (like eyes, nose, lips ...)

Is there anyway we can make a model that can edit for example the nose type/size or any related works already published?